# How to analyze boot.oat crash log?( 'linkToDeath(): recipient must be non-NULL')

Tags: android, android-ndk, crash-dumps

APP crash comes during switch Android User from Owner to Guest.

core crash logs refer below :

```
08-12 23:46:03.724 27197 27197 F libc    : Fatal signal 6 (SIGABRT), code -6 in tid 27197 (com.dolby)
08-12 23:46:03.855   312   312 F DEBUG   : *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** ***
08-12 23:46:03.888   312   312 F DEBUG   : Build fingerprint: 'Lenovo/TB-X103F/TB-X103F:6.0.1/LenovoTB-X103F/TB-X103F_S000013_160813_ROW:user/release-keys'
08-12 23:46:03.889   312   312 F DEBUG   : Revision: '0'
08-12 23:46:03.889   312   312 F DEBUG   : ABI: 'arm'
08-12 23:46:03.893   312   312 F DEBUG   : pid: 27197, tid: 27197, name: com.dolby  >>> com.dolby <<<
08-12 23:46:03.893   312   312 F DEBUG   : signal 6 (SIGABRT), code -6 (SI_TKILL), fault addr --------
08-12 23:46:03.940   312   312 F DEBUG   : Abort message: 'linkToDeath(): recipient must be non-NULL'
08-12 23:46:03.941   312   312 F DEBUG   :     r0 00000000  r1 00006a3d  r2 00000006  r3 b6fadb7c
08-12 23:46:03.942   312   312 F DEBUG   :     r4 b6fadb84  r5 b6fadb34  r6 00000002  r7 0000010c
08-12 23:46:03.942   312   312 F DEBUG   :     r8 00000000  r9 00000000  sl 00000000  fp b7226ccc
08-12 23:46:03.942   312   312 F DEBUG   :     ip 00000006  sp be9062f0  lr b6d2ed85  pc b6d31174  cpsr 400f0010
08-12 23:46:03.993   312   312 F DEBUG   : 
08-12 23:46:03.993   312   312 F DEBUG   : backtrace:
08-12 23:46:03.993   312   312 F DEBUG   :     #00 pc 00044174  /system/lib/libc.so (tgkill+12)
08-12 23:46:03.994   312   312 F DEBUG   :     #01 pc 00041d81  /system/lib/libc.so (pthread_kill+32)
08-12 23:46:03.994   312   312 F DEBUG   :     #02 pc 0001ba2f  /system/lib/libc.so (raise+10)
08-12 23:46:03.995   312   312 F DEBUG   :     #03 pc 00018be1  /system/lib/libc.so (__libc_android_abort+34)
08-12 23:46:03.995   312   312 F DEBUG   :     #04 pc 000167a8  /system/lib/libc.so (abort+4)
08-12 23:46:03.995   312   312 F DEBUG   :     #05 pc 0000864b  /system/lib/libcutils.so (__android_log_assert+86)
08-12 23:46:03.996   312   312 F DEBUG   :     #06 pc 0001a823  /system/lib/libbinder.so (_ZN7android8BpBinder11linkToDeathERKNS_2spINS_7IBinder14DeathRecipientEEEPvj+86)
08-12 23:46:03.997   312   312 F DEBUG   :     #07 pc 0009426f  /system/lib/libmedia.so (_ZN7android11AudioEffect3setEPK13effect_uuid_sS3_iPFviPvS4_ES4_ii+530)
08-12 23:46:03.997   312   312 F DEBUG   :     #08 pc 000943ed  /system/lib/libmedia.so (_ZN7android11AudioEffectC2EPKcRKNS_8String16ES2_iPFviPvS6_ES6_ii+156)
08-12 23:46:03.998   312   312 F DEBUG   :     #09 pc 00002595  /system/lib/libaudioeffect_jni.so
08-12 23:46:03.998   312   312 F DEBUG   :     #10 pc 02affcd3  /system/framework/arm/boot.oat (offset 0x1ef2000)
```

My analyse:

1. arm-linux-androideabi-addr2line -C -e ../tmp/libaudioeffect_jni.so 00002595

   > frameworks/base/media/jni/audioeffect/android_media_AudioEffect.cpp:355
2. arm-linux-androideabi-addr2line -C -e ../tmp/libmedia.so 000943ed

   > frameworks/av/media/libmedia/AudioEffect.cpp:88
3. arm-linux-androideabi-addr2line -C -e ../tmp/libmedia.so 0009426f

   > frameworks/av/media/libmedia/AudioEffect.cpp:158
   >
   > IInterface:asBinder(iEffect)->linkToDeath(mIEffectClient);
4. oatdump [image: boot.oat]

Question:

- Is it correct for me to dump oat file?
- It's all the *even number* of oatdump address(Why show me 02affcd3 here?It's same a odd number)
- How can we pull the oat file which was parsed under android devices folder?
- What's your suggestion for this issue?

Answer (score 0):

There is no single way to analyse crash dumps. Each one is unique and requires individual treatment. Nevertheless there is one common step - converting backtrace addresses to lines / numbers. You did it with `addr2line`. It is a bit tedious and to make things easier you can use [`ndk-stack`](https://developer.android.com/ndk/guides/ndk-stack.html). It does absolutely the same but in more convenient way.

Lets back to crash. as we see the problem is somewhere in framework code, not in your app. Actually this is an assert that was thrown by `BpBinder::linkToDeath()`. I guess this is a kind of bug in system and you can do nothing with it. Another reason to treat it as a system bug is the fact that `BpBinder`'s method was called from `android::AudioEffect` class. Actual audio effect implementation is provided by vendor and probably that binder was used to communicate between generic code and device-specific implementation. Such implementations may be not well-tested or reviewed since much less people work on it than on generic, cross-device code.

To figure out that it is not related to your code - create minimal application that uses audio effects in a way similar to your and try reproduce problem by switching between users.

Comment: Thank your answer.Yes, I know that there is no single way to analyse crash dumps. anyway, I want to convert the crash dump address to lines/numbers.What's my puzzled that how can we convert the oat file ?such as ` 02affcd3  /system/framework/arm/boot.oat (offset 0x1ef2000)`

Comment: @caopeng OAT files are regular ELF files, so you may use them in the same way as `.so` files, both for `addr2line` and `ndk-stack`. Of course they must contain debug data.  In other way there are no benefits.